# [SymmetricDS]: Missing changes in SYM_DATA

Tags: symmetricds

I have new records insert into source database but some records are not synced to target database. When I look into SYM_DATA, between 2 consecutive insert  there are some update event triggered to the same table but different row. Log file has deadlocks error but after retry becomes OK.

My question is can SymmetricDS trigger update and insert if both event type happen together ? How to avoid deadlocks and make sure no missing records to sync from source to target ?

Answer (score 0):

Data can not be synced only if it hasn't been inserted or editing data updated in the database. SymmetricDs extraction of data happens in the same transaction as the application uses. Check if there data has been successfully inserted or updates. Maybe some transactions have been rolled back. If they have been successfully committed order the table sym_data by its primary key data_id description to be sure you haven't missed a row.

Comment: In the source it is inserted successfully. Only it is not synced to target. That cause my record count not tally. I'd order by data_id already

Comment: have you checked if triggers were disabled?

Comment: No not disabled, but in the log file, there is some create trigger for (I/U/D) running around that time. Could it be the cause ?

Comment: yes, it could if the trigger wasn't created when the insert happened